# Let $S$ = the set of all values $n$<100 satisfying that $ 4^n+3^n+2^n+1^n $ is a multiple of 3 How many values in $S$ are there?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S$ = the set of all values $n$<100 satisfying that
$ 4^n+3^n+2^n+1^n $
is a multiple of 3
How many values in $S$ are there?

my attempt to solve was about substitution of $n$ values  , and i noticed that the only the even ones work
 i.e $n$ = 2,4,6,.....
is there any way to prove that ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Write out the first few cases...does that suggest a pattern?

Comment: @lulu i have tried substitution of n values and  noticed that the only the even ones work   , is there any way to prove that ?

Comment: @prayersmith You can use modular arithmetic to prove this. Refer to my answer for a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take modulo 3 of the expression. If you are not familiar with modular arithmetic, you should probably look it up as it is integral to solving this problem.
$$4^n + 3^n + 2^n + 1^n \equiv 1^n + 0^n + 2^n + 1^n \equiv 2^n + 2 \mod 3$$
Now we find for which values $2^n \equiv 1 \mod 3$.
$$2^1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$$
$$2^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$$
$$2^3 \equiv 2 \mod 3$$
$$2^4 \equiv 1 \mod 3$$
As you can see, a pattern quickly develops. You can also prove this pattern by writing $2^n \equiv (-1)^n \mod 3$. So, for each even $n$ besides $0$, it will be divisible by $3$. There are $49$ even integers less than 100, so the answer is $49$.

Comment: thank you very much  , elegant soln

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* $4^n+3^n+2^n+1^n \equiv 2^n + 2\equiv (-1)^n-1\bmod 3$ for $n\ge 1$.